# Adding multiple class names using a template literal

Tags: javascript, html

Simple question I'm sure, but I can't see why this code:

```
const addDiv = (test) => {
    const markup = `
      <div class=${test? "name":"name name-active"}></div>
    `;
    element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
};
```

results in `<div class="name" name-active="">` rather than `<div class="name name-active">`

Have I made a simple error, or is it behaviour I just don't understand? Thanks

Comment: What type of variable is `test`? Boolean? String? You can have a serious trouble around truthy/falsy values here.

Comment: The issue is that you do not have quotes around the value of your class attribute.  `class='${test? "name":"name name-active"}'`

Comment: Thanks Taplar, and k3llydev, I'm actually testing a number I just wrote it that way for simplicity, so no worries there thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the double quotes inside the template literal are not part of the outer string, so you will have to wrap the class value in quotes outside.

make sure `class="` and `"` are outside the template literals

```
const addDiv = (test) => {
    const markup = `
      <div class="${test? "name":"name name-active"}"></div>
    `;
    element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
};
```

Comment: I mean, I'm an idiot, but I can also see how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you need to add the quotes as escaped characters in your returned string `${test? "name":"\"name name-active\""}`

Answer (score 0):

```
const addDiv = (test) => {
    const markup = document.createElement('div');
    markup.className = test ? "name" : "name active";
    element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
};
```

Comment: Try to add some explanations of your answer code so that readers will know why it works.